# connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

Why does it trying to connect to localhost when I directly specified "db" as HOST?

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    web-app:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./myapp:/myapp

        command: >
            sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0:8000"

    db:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        volumes:
            - ./myapp_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=Test_overflow_db
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'Test_overflow_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Also once I had slightly different error
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at db ("172.20.0.2"), port 5432 failed: Connection refused`, but I tried some stuff after and this has never shown again

Comment: Have you checked the database logs? Have you made sure that the database is still running and accepting connections?

Comment: @KevinKopf yes man. Direct citation from logs `overflow-db-1       | 2023-11-10 07:50:51.774 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following docker-compose configuration allows me to setup a database and django app configuration using your selected values. The main differences being:

- Added `PGDATA` environment variable.
- Added `links` to web-app.
- Moves from a mounted folder to a volume.

```
services:
    web-app:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./myapp:/app

        command: "python manage.py runserver 0:8000"
        links:
            - db

    db:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        volumes:
            - myapp_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=Test_overflow_db
            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

volumes:
    myapp_data:
```

My django settings file database section looked like this: The package versions are:

- django = "^4.2.7"
- psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.9"

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': "Test_overflow_db",
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro, it shows me `validating C:\projects\overflow\docker-compose.yml: services.volumes Additional property overflow_pg_data is not allowed` when I add `volumes: ` section. It also happened before when I tried something similar myself

Comment: Wow, now when I commented `volumes: ` section I caught this `overflow-web-app-1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "db" (172.20.0.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused`. @mattseymour

Comment: This sounds like a configuration issue on your machine with docker and windows. Have you ever had any docker networking working? If not I would uninstall the docker client, and re-try the setup process. It could be something is not configured correctly.

Comment: Actually yes, there were a few networks running previously on this computer, but for now any other container is shut down. How can I check if problem is with some of the previous projects? I also see "pg_data" volume of another project has "in use" status but actual container exited for two weeks already. Can this be a core of the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried so many different things and made a lot of progress, but in the end I returned to your answer and finally it worked fine. I can not recall what exactly did the thing, but thank you